# Nth Term of Fractions

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do I work out the Nth term of these fractions?
$$1,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{9},\frac{1}{16},\frac{1}{25},\dots$$
Would I need to change them all into decimals but that would be quite complicated and then go from there? Yes I can see a pattern, the denominators are squared numbers but what do I do after? I know that answer is going to have a $^2$ in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you recognize the sequence that the numbers in the denominators form? 1,4,9,16,25,.. is a well known sequence. If you've figured that out, it will be quite easy to write down a direct expression for the nth term of the sequence.

Comment: Well, that only works for the first two number 1 and 4. All the numbers in the sequence are squares. If you figure out which squares, the exercise will be quite easy.

Comment: I don't know. It's not $3n-2^2$ or $3n^2-2$

Comment: It's much easier than you might think. Try $n^2$

Comment: oh ok... pretty obvious. thankxs x:)x

Answer (score 1):

See if you can find any pattern in the fractions or their reciprocals.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: A pattern is evident by looking at the denominators. They are all squares, specifically $n^2$. You can think that the first term is $1/1^2$, for consistency.

Answer (score -1):

$$T(n)= \frac{1}{n^2}$$ where $n$ is greater then equal to 0.

Comment: Well, you ought to [learn it](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), then.